# inject akka actors using guice in play 2.5

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, guice

In Play 2.2, I've created GlobalActorProducer class

```
import akka.actor.{Props, IndirectActorProducer, Actor}
import play.api.Play

class GlobalActorProducer[T <: Actor](val aClass: Class[T]) extends IndirectActorProducer {

  def produce(): T = Play.current.global.getControllerInstance(aClass)

  def actorClass: Class[T] = aClass
}

object GlobalActorProducer {
  def apply[T <: Actor](targetClass: Class[T]): Props = Props.create(classOf[GlobalActorProducer[T]], targetClass)
}
```

I want to upgrade play framework to 2.5.  Play.current is deprecated in play 2.5 so I modified this class by using Injector, but the injector is always Null.  How do I need to make this class work on play 2.5?

```
import akka.actor.{Props, IndirectActorProducer, Actor}
import javax.inject.Inject
import com.google.inject.Injector

class GlobalActorProducer[T <: Actor](val aClass: Class[T]) extends IndirectActorProducer {

  @Inject private var injector : Injector = _

　def produce(): T = injector.getInstance(aClass)

  def actorClass: Class[T] = aClass
}

object GlobalActorProducer {
  def apply[T <: Actor](targetClass: Class[T]): Props = Props.create(classOf[GlobalActorProducer[T]], targetClass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Injecting `Actor`s is a bad practice. ActorRef are created by actor system in a special way without exposing the actual object instead exposing the ActorRef (handle).

Solution:

The idea is to Inject `ActorSystem` and then create actors using

`actorSystem.actorOf`

Answer (score 0):

You want to make use of the Akka Guice support provide by Play in the play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport namespace, as discussed in [Dependency Injecting Actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka).

> Play provides some helpers to help providing actor bindings. These allow the actor itself to be dependency injected, and allows the actor ref for the actor to be injected into other components. To bind an actor using these helpers, create a module as described in the dependency injection documentation, then mix in the AkkaGuiceSupport trait and use the bindActor method to bind the actor:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import actors.ConfiguredActor

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[ConfiguredActor]("configured-actor")
  }
}

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (@Named("configured-actor") configuredActor: ActorRef, components: ControllerComponents)
                            (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(components) {

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds

  def getConfig = Action.async {
    (configuredActor ? GetConfig).mapTo[String].map { message =>
      Ok(message)
    }
  }
}
```